# Make the build fail on production but not on development mode

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently developing an Angular application and was wondering if I can make the build fail on production, but not in local development.

For instance, I have a complex login logic, which I want to go around while developing.
For this, I only need to introduce a single line in `app.component.ts`:

```
ngOnInit(): { 
  this.userservice.mockLoginUser(); 
  ... 
}
```

Is there any way to make this line run in development mode, but fail hard if I forget about it in production? For instance, create a command that only fails upon `ng build --prod` (but not for `ng serve`)?

Just using `environment.ts` is not an option, as I do not want to pollute the code base, I want to physically delete it (as well as the `mockLoginUser` method), as I only need it in a few cases. My other idea was to create a tslint rule that will prevent it from going to production, but could not find any.

Comment: You could implement a custom tslint rule that you'd run only when doing a build in production mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why not to use unit tests?**

In one of project I'm working in, we have micro-frontend app which is hard to authenticate when running standalone (without container).

I often setting my development never-ending JWT in `ngOnInit`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.setJwt('ey....');
}
```

Then I have simple unit test which is looking over that:

```
it('should not initialize JWT on component initialization', () => {
    const authService = TestBed.inject(AuthService);
    spyOn(authService, 'setJwt');

    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(authService.setJwt).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Thanks to this I never forget to delete this "development line of code". My code base is not polluted which unnecesary statements. Furhermore I'm even not able to push code to any branch, because our gitlab pipeline run tests automatically.